# Unable to replace splash screen image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-drawable, android-launcher

I have an issue with setting new splash screen image in my app. I have a splash screen activity and splash theme for it:

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

When I set new splash.png in my drawable folder my application still uses an old one, despite the fact that it was overridden by the new .png file. This concerns devices which had my app already installed. I don't face this issue when installing new apk with new splash for the first time. Seems like this old one splash.png was cached somewhere. How is it possible?

Comment: change the name

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes. What has worked for me is changing the file name, deleting the older file. Then,

```
File -> Invalidate and Restart
```

and then you can refactor your filename to the old one again. 
 Hope it works for you, good luck!